# Why does a multi-word Doctrine search cause MySQL to use up to 300% CPU?

Tags: php, mysql, search, symfony1, doctrine

I have a table using Doctrine's Searchable behaviour, which works well for single word queries. However I've noticed that when a query includes a space, the page hangs and I can't get any response out of refreshing the page etc.

If I open Activity Monitor on my Mac, or SSH then 'top' in Ububntu, MySQL is running a process at up to 300% CPU. I have to kill the process in order to get things running normally again.

These are the SQL queries generated by Doctrine:

For a single word query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_results FROM hotel h WHERE h.is_active = '1' 
AND h.id IN (SELECT id FROM hotel_index WHERE keyword = 'samui' GROUP 
BY id)
```

For a multi-word query with a space in it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_results FROM hotel h WHERE h.is_active = '1' 
AND h.id IN (SELECT id FROM hotel_index WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM 
hotel_index WHERE keyword = 'sala') AND id IN (SELECT id FROM 
hotel_index WHERE keyword = 'samui') GROUP BY id)
```

I've tried a few things like adding double quote marks around the 2 words.

Thanks

Comment: you may want to look into http://sphinxsearch.com or Lucene if you can't get doctrine working faster

Comment: It's simple...  Because MySQL needs to process a lot of rows, so it uses a lot of CPU.  Run the query through [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) and that should tell you quite a bit about what's going on...  But you're doing 3 joins on 3 temporary tables, so it's going to be slow...

Comment: How can some thing run at 300% cpu?

Comment: @Petoj: on a 3-core `CPU`, easily.

Comment: i have a 4-core cpu and i still only use 100%, but im using windows...

Comment: @Petoj: install Ubuntu, you'll get whole 400%!

Comment: SELECT * FROM overclock WHERE possible AND LN2=true

Comment: @Quassnoi: omg that awesome! but i have HT on all 4 cores so that might result in 800%?

Comment: to re-iterate what others say - the doctrine searchable behaviour doesn't really work/scale well beyond really small datasets or else basic usage with larger datasets. Something dedicated like sphinx or solr will serve you much better

Comment: I remember looking into Lucene (via the Zend Framework component).  Think I left it once I discovered how easy Doctrine Searchable was to implement, but looks like I'll have to revisit it, but I'll check out Solr and Sphinx too.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible to make Doctrine remove `GROUP BY` from the query?

It has no meaning and only degrades performance. This would perform much better:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS num_results
FROM    hotel h
WHERE   h.is_active = '1' 
        AND h.id IN
        (
        SELECT id
        FROM   hotel_index
        WHERE  keyword = 'sala'
        )
        AND h.id IN
        (
        SELECT id
        FROM   hotel_index
        WHERE  keyword = 'samui'
        )
```

, provided that you have indexes on `hotel(is_active)` and `hotel_index (keyword)`

You could also rewrite it like this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS num_results
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    hotel_index
        WHERE   keyword IN ('sala', 'samui')
        GROUP BY
                id
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
        ) q
JOIN    hotel h
ON      h.id = q.id
        AND h.is_active = '1'
```

which would be yet more efficient.

Comment: I haven't found anything from Doctrine indicating how to customise the auto-generated search query.  At the moment I'm thinking I might have to just replicate the (correct) query manually and run that.